# Limit points in closed finite sets?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

In ch. 2 of Rudin's Principles of Math Analysis,  definition 2.18 gives the definition of a closed set: $E$ is closed if every limit point of $E$ is an interior point of $E$. After that,  theorem 2.20 and the following corollary clearly state that a finite point set has no limit points. Yet,  the immediate example below clearly states that a nonempty finite set is closed. What exactly am I missing because this sounds like a clear contradiction?

Comment: There is no contradiction. Let $E$ be a nonempty finite set. Then $$\{ \mbox{limit points of } E \} = \emptyset \subseteq E^°$$ so $E$ is closed.

Comment: Something is not right about this. Are you sure that your definition of closed set is correct?

Comment: Crostul,  is E^° the closure of E?

Answer (score 1):

With the definition the way you write it, the interval $  [0,1] $ would not be closed, since  $0$ is not interior. What 2.18 says is that $E $ is closed if every limit point belongs to $E $ (no "interior").

Comment: Yes,  I noticed my error. Thank you for clarifying.